# Return objects grouped by interval of times in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Tweet.

Each Tweet object has an attribute called tweet_created_at which basically says when that tweet was published.

I would like to do a query which returns me the Tweets by interval of time, so at the end I would like to have:

```
tweets_by_interval = { 'from_0_to_3' => [TweetObject1, TweetObject2..], 'from_4_to_7' => [...], 'from_8_to_11' => [...], 'from_12_to_15' => [...], 'from_16_to_19' => [...], 'from_20_to_23' => [...] }
```

So each member in the Hash would mean: Those tweets which were created from hour X to hour Y.

How can I do that using ActiveRecord query interface?

Comment: what kind of db are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this either with ActiveRecord/SQL or with Ruby. You can use `group_by` method with the latter approach, as follows:

```
TIME_INTERVALS = (0...24).collect {|hour| base = hour-hour%4 ; "from_#{base}_to_#{base+3}".to_sym}

def interval(time)
  TIME_INTERVALS[time.hour]
end

Tweet.all.group_by {|tweet| interval(tweet.tweet_created_at)}
```

I tested this with the following:

```
class Tweet

  def initialize
    @time = DateTime.new(1,1,1,rand(24))
  end

  def self.all
    15.times.collect {Tweet.new}
  end

  def tweet_created_at
    @time
  end

  def inspect
    'Tweet'+@time.hour.to_s
  end

end
```

which produced:

`=> {:from_4_to_7=>[Tweet5, Tweet7, Tweet7], :from_12_to_15=>[Tweet13, Tweet13, Tweet14], :from_0_to_3=>[Tweet2, Tweet2], :from_20_to_23=>[Tweet22, Tweet20, Tweet21], :from_8_to_11=>[Tweet10, Tweet9, Tweet10], :from_16_to_19=>[Tweet17]}`